# Oracle IAM weblogic server issue

Tags: java, oracle-apex, oracle12c, weblogic12c

I'm facing Oracle IAM WebLogic Error, I have recreated the schema and Domain

Location - /u01/app/oracle/iam/user_projects/domains/niam_domain

created the

```
boot.properties
```

file also

```
username=weblogic 
password=Welcome1
```

`oracle.security.jps.JpsException: oracle.security.jps.service.keystore.KeyStoreServiceException: Failed to perform cryptographic operation`

Comment: It should be [`boot.properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/core.1111/e12035/create_domain_im.htm#IMEDG382), not `theboot.property`; and should contain `username` and `password`, not `pass`. And the username/password have to be the ones you specified in the 'Create New Domain' step.

Comment: my bad, the exact details are
(username=weblogic
password=Welcome1)  file = boot.properties 
let me know if you know anything regarding this error.

Comment: OK, you can edit the question to correct it. If you're sure everything is correct and in the right place, [are you using the right JDK?](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2579745_1.html)

Comment: yes,  java version "1.8.0_291

Comment: @AlexPoole can't open the solution as I don't have my oracle support account

Comment: Was everything run and created using that JDK version? Or do you have multiple versions available and some steps might have run under an older version (lower than 1.8.0_221)? Make sure the environment and all scripts (like setDomainEnv) show the JDK path you expect. If they don't you might need to reinstall.

Comment: Everything was installed and configured on the same JDK version, and no multiple JDK is installed in Environment, The environment and script shows the  expected JDK path.